# Connecting SLOTS in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a context menu and edit menu. I want to connect context menu slots with the edit menu.
Like EDIT menu has menu Items: cut, copy and paste

My context menu slots are:

```
void CadGraphicsScene::cut(getEntity *obj)
{
    // id of item pasted is kept same as that of the item being cut
    removeItem(obj);
    clipboardStack::instance()->push(obj->clone(contextItemId));
}

void CadGraphicsScene::copy(getEntity *obj)
{
    // id of item pasted is one more than total number of items in the scene
    clipboardStack::instance()->push(obj->clone(++id));
}

void CadGraphicsScene::paste(const QPointF &pos)
{
    // gets the items cut/copy from clipboardStack to paste
    getEntity *pasteEntity = clipboardStack::instance()->pop();

    if (pasteEntity->type() == Point::Type)
    {
        Point *itemPtr = dynamic_cast<Point *>(pasteEntity);
        itemPtr->position = pos;
        drawEntity(itemPtr);
    }

    if (pasteEntity->type() == Line::Type)
    {
        Line *itemPtr = dynamic_cast<Line *>(pasteEntity);
        itemPtr->startP = pos;

        /* calculates difference between startP of line being cut/copy and line
         * being pasted for proper pasting of line
         */
        differenceX = itemPtr->startP.x() - lineStartPoint.x();
        differenceY = itemPtr->startP.y() - lineStartPoint.y();
        itemPtr->endP = QPointF(lineEndPoint.x() + differenceX,
                                lineEndPoint.y() + differenceY);
        drawEntity(itemPtr);
    }

    if (pasteEntity->type() == Circle::Type)
    {
        Circle *itemPtr = dynamic_cast<Circle *>(pasteEntity);
        itemPtr->centerP = pos;
        drawEntity(itemPtr);
    }

    if (pasteEntity->type() == Ellipse::Type)
    {
        Ellipse *itemPtr = dynamic_cast<Ellipse *>(pasteEntity);
        itemPtr->p1 = pos;
        drawEntity(itemPtr);
    }

    if (pasteEntity->type() == Text::Type)
    {
        Text *itemPtr = dynamic_cast<Text *>(pasteEntity);
        itemPtr->position = pos;
        drawEntity(itemPtr);
    }

    setMode(NoMode);
}
```

//context menu actions

```
 void CadGraphicsScene::menuAction(QAction *action)
    {
        if (action == cutAction)
        {
            cut(static_cast<getEntity *>(contextItem));
        }

        else if (action == copyAction)
        {
            copy(static_cast<getEntity *>(contextItem));
        }

        else if (action == pasteAction)
        {
            paste(contextPosition);
        }

}
```

How can the same be done from edit menu? How can the same slots be used?

for cut in the edit menu I made another slot:

```
void CadgraphicsScene::cut()
{
cutAction
}

connect(actionCut, SIGNAL(triggered), this, SLOT(cut()));
```

Comment: Im not sure I understand your question, but if you have c++11 and qt 5+ you can connect a signal to any function:
`connect(my_action, &QAction::triggered, [=]{/*call any function or do anything*/});`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse the same slots in your application's Edit menu, just use existing `cutAction`, `copyAction` and `pasteAction` actions when constructing it. So if you has established the connections for that actions the same slots will be called both when user triggers actions from context menu and from Edit menu.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please do check and rply, this is not working.